# Post from a form in an iFrame to a popup window in the parent window

Tags: jquery, forms, post, popup

I have spent some time trying to get this to work from various similar questions but can't find a solution that matches exactly what I'm looking for.

So I have a pretty basic form with 3 radio buttons which is embedded in an iframe on another page. When I click one of the radio buttons this code automatically submits the response

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('input[name=rating]').change(function(){
$('form').submit(); });
});
</script>
```

Now at the moment my submit action for my form looks like this

```
<form method="POST" action="https://formspree.io/myformspreeurl" target="_parent">
```

So this successfully submits the response from the iframe code but on the parent page.

What I want to happen is that when one of the radio buttons on the form is selected it automatically submits but into a pop up window (to complete a captcha) so that the user doesn't have to come away from the parent page.

Possible or am I over complicating things?

Thanks for any help,

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
<form action="" method="post" target="_blank">
```

and this should open a new page and submit your data to it. I see you are using jQuery so you could change target dynamically based on the specific radio buttons selection using:

```
$("form").prop("target", targetValue);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem with using _blank is that formspree doesn't see the "POST" command when I do this. From my research it seems submitting from an iframe to a "_blank" tab doesn't actually pass the selected information. "_parent" definitely does pass the information but unfortunately the parent page redirects to complete the formspree captcha which is what I want to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

The use ajax to submit the form dynamicly and you wont be reloading your parent page, if i undestand true.

```
$.ajax({
     type:'POST',
     url:'https://formspree.io/myformspreeurl',
     data:$('form').serialize(),
     success: function (e){

     //what you want to do after submiting//

     }
});
```